# Starting multiple activities and getting result before starting the next one

Tags: android, android-intent

I am making a quiz app, my MainActivity(main menu) launches QuestionActivity using startActivityForResult, in QuestionActivity (Question text and answer buttons). After the user has answered the question, I want to send a boolean back a to MainActivity to update the score which then can be pushed into the next intent, in the Question Activity, I display the score in the Actionbar.

The problem is when I answer one question, setResult and Finish Runs but onActivityResult does not, after I answer all questions then OnActivityResult runs 10 times.

**How can I get onActivityResult to run after I answer each question, not at the end?**
Do I need to use intent flags?

### Extra Info

In MainActivity, when the user starts the quiz:

```
//Called when user clicks quiz
//Creates the list of questions and then asks them.
public void makeQuiz(View view) {
    //Pick the questions for the quiz
    question[] quiz = new question[10]; //A quiz with 10 questions
    for (int i = 0; i < quiz.length; i++) {
        quiz[i] = myDBHelper.pickQuestion();
        askQuestion(view, quiz[i],i,qscore);
        Log.d("Asked question", Integer.toString(i));
    }
}
```

Ask Question is used to start the QuestionActivity:

```
    //Creates a question and then passes it though to the question view.
public boolean askQuestion(View view, question q, int questionNum, int qscore){
    question q1 = q;
    Log.d("Correct Ans",q.CorrectAns);
    Intent question = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("QUESTION", q.QuestionText);
    extras.putString("MODULE", q.Module);
    extras.putString("CORRECT_ANS",q.CorrectAns);
    extras.putString("ANS1", q.WAns[0]);
    extras.putString("ANS2", q.WAns[1]);
    extras.putString("ANS3", q.WAns[2]);
    extras.putInt("qscore",qscore);
    question.putExtras(extras); //Passing the question to the QuestionActivity

    startActivityForResult(question,1);
    return true;
}
```

In QuestionActivity, When the user answers the question correctly:

```
//Pass back that we got the correct answer
resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("ANSWER",true);
setResult(1, resultIntent);
Log.d("True", "Set result has been called");
finish();
```

Back in MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    //Check which event we are responding to
        Log.d("onActivityResult", "called"); //This never runs
        if(resultCode == 1){
            //Do something with the intent
            //if q is correct, update the score in shared prefrences,
            Boolean result = data.getBooleanExtra("ANSWER",false);
            Log.d("ANSWER IS ", Boolean.toString(result));
            qscore += result ? 1:0; //This updated score is then pushed into the next intent so it can be displayed in the next question activity. 
        }
}
```

Comment: how do u start the QuestionActivity

Comment: @J.N using StartActivityForResult, see my edit for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so this is your problem you start the activity for result with:

```
startActivityForResult(question,questionNum);
```

so questionNum is your requestCode

but when you finish the QuestionActivity you finish it like this:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
```

so here your request code is the value of Activity.RESULT_OK

you need them to be equal.

**Edit:**

for your request in the comment look at this:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 123131;
private Stack<Intent> intentStack = new Stack<>();

//Called when user clicks quiz
//Creates the list of questions and then asks them.
    public void makeQuiz(View view) {
        //Pick the questions for the quiz
        question[] quiz = new question[10]; //A quiz with 10 questions
        for (int i = 0; i < quiz.length; i++) {
            quiz[i] = myDBHelper.pickQuestion();
            askQuestion(view, quiz[i], i, qscore);
            Log.d("Asked question", Integer.toString(i));
        }
        startActivityForResult(intentStack.pop(), REQUEST_CODE);
    }
//Creates a question and then passes it though to the question view.
public boolean askQuestion(View view, question q, int questionNum, int qscore) {
    question q1 = q;
    Log.d("Correct Ans", q.CorrectAns);
    Intent question = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("QUESTION", q.QuestionText);
    extras.putString("MODULE", q.Module);
    extras.putString("CORRECT_ANS", q.CorrectAns);
    extras.putString("ANS1", q.WAns[0]);
    extras.putString("ANS2", q.WAns[1]);
    extras.putString("ANS3", q.WAns[2]);
    extras.putInt("qscore", qscore);
    question.putExtras(extras); //Passing the question to the QuestionActivity

    intentStack.push(question);

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //Check which event we are responding to
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Do something with the intent
        //if q is correct, update the score in shared prefrences,
        Boolean result = data.getBooleanExtra("ANSWER", false);
        Log.d("ANSWER IS ", Boolean.toString(result));
        qscore += result ? 1 : 0;
        if(!intentStack.isEmpty()){
            startActivityForResult(intentStack.pop(), REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, after changing them both to the same value, it did not work. I put a Log.d above the result code check and onActivityResult does not run until all questions have been answered.

Comment: U should manage a stack of activities and pop an activity every time on the onActivityResult after your QuestionActivity finish and not start them all together at the same time

Comment: Please could you give a little more info on how to do this?

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I am pulling the score as an intent into display it in the action bar. As this method creates all the intents at the start, how can I pass the score through?

Comment: I originally was going to use shared preferences but I wanted to reduce disk usage, hence when I am passing if the question was correct back then I was trying to pass the score forward into the next intent that gets made.

Comment: You can now count the score in the main activity as the intents from each question activity goes to the main activity in the on activity result when every question is answered. Btw if this helped please mark my answer as correct ty and gl friend

Comment: I am counting the score in the main activity, but I can't pass it into QuestionActivity as the stack is being filled at the start so the value of the score I am pushing back into the intent is always zero. I would need to update the stack after every question. I will mark this as correct if this can be done. I have updated the question to explain this better.

Comment: U can pop an intent from the stack add the intent the score and then start the activity

Comment: Thank you, that seems obvious now. I have marked as correct, thank you for helping so fast.

Comment: glad to help gl